# Rails ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the `routes` table with fields `from_airport_id` and `to_airport_id`.

Let's say:

```
route = Route.find(1)
```

The question: how to define the ActiveRecord associations, that route.from_airport would be equal to Airport.find(route.from_airport_id) and route.to_airport = Airport.find(route.to_airport_id)?

In other words:

from_airport_id => airport.id

to_airport_id => airport.id

I guess, the query should be:

```
route = Route.find(1).includes(:airports)
```

But how do I select two records from the same table at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
has_many :from_airports, :class_name => "AirPort",
:foreign_key => "from_airport_id"


has_many :to_airports, :class_name => "AirPort",
:foreign_key => "to_airport_id"
```